# list subscribers from channel

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Can I get a list of all subscribers from a channel that's not mine? I.e. I want to get all **subscribers from pewdiepie** channel. Today, with the Youtube API v3, I can get his *subscriptions*, but I do not found any documentations about get his subscribers. Anyone knows something about it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribers is a list of the people currently subscribed to a channel.

If you check [Channels resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource) returned by channel.list the best you can do is get the subscriberCount.   So no you can not get a list of the subscribers to a channel.   This has nothing to do with if you own the channel or not the data does not appear to be exposed by the API.

Background info:

> A [subscription](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions) resource contains information about a YouTube user
>   subscription. A subscription notifies a user when new videos are added
>   to a channel or when another user takes one of several actions on
>   YouTube, such as uploading a video, rating a video, or commenting on a
>   video.

Request subscriptions for a channel i do not own

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&channelId=UC4rasfm9J-X4jNl9SvXp8xA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.subscription",
    "reason": "subscriptionForbidden",
    "message": "The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions."
 }
}
```

The YouTube API will not return subscriptions for a channel that the authenticated user does not own.

Comment: I have the same problem. Couldn't figure out how to resolve this. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: This is the answer it's not possible to see this information about a channel that is not yours.

Comment: @VladimirKovalchuk Oauth grants an application authorization to see data that the authenticated user has access to.   If the authenticated user doesn't have access to that information then Oauth isnt going to give you access to it.  Its called security.

Comment: @DaImTo sorry I got your answer

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo it has nothing to do with security

Comment: Did i say it did? Seven years ago?